# How to process CASes produced by CAS Multiplier concurrently

Tags: uima

I am implementing UIMA pipeline with CASMultiplier and UIMA AS. I have a Segmenter Analysis Engine (A CASMultiplier) and a Analysis Engine (Annotator A). I created a Aggregate Analysis Engine of the Segmenter and Annotator A, and then I create a UIMA AS Deployment descriptor file with intention, the Segmenter produces CASes, and then the Annotator A process with CASes concurrently. The contents of the aggregate analysis engine descriptor file and the deployment descriptor file are as following:

AAE descriptor file:

```
    <analysisEngineDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
    <frameworkImplementation>org.apache.uima.java</frameworkImplementation>
    <primitive>false</primitive>

    <delegateAnalysisEngineSpecifiers>
        <delegateAnalysisEngine key="Segmenter">
            <import location="../cas_multiplier/SimpleTextSegmenter.xml"/>
        </delegateAnalysisEngine>

        <delegateAnalysisEngine key="AnnotatorA">
            <import location="AnnotatorA.xml"/>
    </delegateAnalysisEngine>
    </delegateAnalysisEngineSpecifiers>

    <analysisEngineMetaData>
        <name>Segmenter and AnnotatorA</name>
        <description>Splits a document into pieces and runs Annotator on each 
            piece independently.  All segments are output.</description>

        <configurationParameters/>
    <configurationParameterSettings/>
    <flowConstraints>
          <fixedFlow>
            <node>Segmenter</node>
            <node>AnnotatorA</node>
          </fixedFlow>
        </flowConstraints>

        <capabilities>
            <capability>
                <inputs/>
                <outputs>
                  <type allAnnotatorFeatures="true">com.trang.uima.types.Target</type>
          <type allAnnotatorFeatures="true">com.eg.uima.types.IntermediateResult</type>
        </outputs>
                <languagesSupported>
                    </languagesSupported>
            </capability>
        </capabilities>
        <operationalProperties>
            <modifiesCas>true</modifiesCas>
            <multipleDeploymentAllowed>true</multipleDeploymentAllowed>
            <outputsNewCASes>true</outputsNewCASes>
        </operationalProperties>
    </analysisEngineMetaData>
</analysisEngineDescription>
```

Deployment descriptor file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><analysisEngineDeploymentDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
  <name>SegmenterAndBackTranstion</name>
  <description>Deploys Segmenter and BackTranskation with 3 instances of BackTransation</description>
  <version/>
  <vendor/>
  <deployment protocol="jms" provider="activemq">
    <casPool numberOfCASes="5" initialFsHeapSize="2000000"/>
    <service>
      <inputQueue endpoint="SegmentAnBackTranslationQueue" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" prefetch="0"/>
      <topDescriptor>
<import location="../../descriptors/langrid_uima/SegmenterAndBackTranslationAE.xml"/>
      </topDescriptor>
      <analysisEngine async="false">
        <scaleout numberOfInstances="5"/>
        <casMultiplier poolSize="8" initialFsHeapSize="2000000" processParentLast="false"/>
        <asyncPrimitiveErrorConfiguration>
          <processCasErrors thresholdCount="0" thresholdWindow="0" thresholdAction="terminate"/>
          <collectionProcessCompleteErrors timeout="0" additionalErrorAction="terminate"/>
        </asyncPrimitiveErrorConfiguration>
      </analysisEngine>
    </service>
  </deployment>
</analysisEngineDeploymentDescription>
```

After have this setting, I run the pipeline, however, it seems the CASes are process synchronously, one at a time. 
Could anyone tell me, what am doing wrong? Is there a way to process CASes produced by CASMultiplier concurrently?

Thank you very much!